# ffmpeg drawtext filename in folder files

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

i want to draw part of the text in my filename to the video file but when i try to putit the loop they multiply and draw the first filename

the filename's have this pattern

123123213__nombre1_32213123_323123.mp4

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

for /r  %%g in (*.mp4) do (

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    (for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%b in ('dir /b *.mp4') do (

       ffmpeg -i %%g -vf "drawbox=y=(ih/PHI)+312:color=black@0.4:width=iw:height=35:t=fill, drawtext=text='Insta\:\@%%b':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h/PHI)+300+th" outdir\%%~ng.mp4
```

pd: another error is when i have a name whit underscore the file make error

Comment: Your example file name has two underscores delimiting the first two fields.  Was that intentional?  if so, you must account for the empty field in your inner for loop.

Comment: yes is intentional because make an error in the result and not al the files have an underscorer

Comment: Your question is unclear. You've told us that you "want to draw part of the text in my filename to the video file", and stated the "the filename's have this pattern, `123123213__nombre1_32213123_323123.mp4`". Then you've completely invalidated the statement by telling us that "not all the files have an underscore", and "when I have a name with an underscore the file makes an error". The worst thing really however is that the only way we are able to determine which part of the filename you're trying to capture, is by reading your failing code. Are you trying to capture the string `nombre1`?

Comment: sory, im trying to print "nombre1" in the video but when i run the code the lopps print the same name in all the videos, some of the videos has more than one underscore